# Can I apply for a Schengen visa in Romania, if I'm not a resident?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, romania

I will be on a business trip to Romania but I have plans to have a vacation in Paris and Italy. Can I apply for a Schengen visa while I'm in Romania? I'm from The Philippines.

Comment: You usually have to apply for a Schengen visa at the consulate competent for your place of residence. Why can't you apply for a Schengen visa in the Philippines before going to Romania?

Comment: My trip to Romania is urgent and I will have no time to apply for visa in the Philippines. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot make a Schengen visa application in Romania without being a resident. Relevant quote from the [Czech consulate in Romania](http://www.mzv.cz/jnp/en/information_for_aliens/short_stay_visa/general_information.html):

> **The applicants file their application in the state of which they are either citizens or holders of a long-term residence permit.**  In case there is no diplomatic mission of the Czech Republic in this state, the application is to be filed at the diplomatic mission which is accredited for that state (usually located in a neighboring state) or at the diplomatic mission of another Schengen Area State if the Czech Republic concluded a representation agreement with this state.

Answer (score -2):

Generally speaking, no. As Tor-Einar pointed out, you have to apply at the consulate for your *place of residence*. And since Romania is an EU member, the French embassy in Romania won't have the staff to process your application.

Comment: 'And since Romania is an EU member, the French embassy in Romania won't have the staff to process your application.' Why do you think so? The French consulates in Romania have of course staff to process visa applications.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, they will not be familiar with the supporting documents a filipino might submit. How are they to evaluate the likelihood of return or the ties to the homeland?

Comment: @o.m. Your answer is basically correct but it could probably be clarified. It's true that French consulates anywhere will be better equipped to deal with locals (that's one of the reasons for the requirement to apply at your place of usual residence) but the fact that Romania is in the EU is not directly relevant. It only means they will have fewer applications but they are still supposed to process Schengen visa application (e.g. from Filipinos who are not merely visitors but residents in Romania).